# How to handle user who only ever edits posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

While going through the "Suggested Edits" review queue, I noticed one [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5942421/tyop)'s edits appearing there several times, with unusually detailed references to meta posts given as reasons in the edit comment.

[image: Suggested edit]

As far as I can tell, each of those edits was pretty much spot-on, not only removing several pieces of fluff and "user" tags, but also in some cases fixing spelling and grammar as well.

Curious, I checked the user's page, and, to my surprise, found that every bit of reputation has come from approved edits - not a single question or answer on the whole site (or any sister sites). The only other things to have affected their reputation was bounties... apparently, this user is currently awarding three bounties on three low-vote questions. What gives?!?

Unlike [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4395049/vvk-aghera) I came across yesterday in that queue (who seemed to be farming rep with LOTS of single-tag edits while ignoring glaring errors in those posts - which I've flagged, and I think they've stopped now), I think this user should actually be commended for cleaning up questions, but I still think it's strange behaviour. Or maybe it isn't, and I just haven't seen it before, but... *only* edits, and rewarding bounties, and no questions/answers/votes cast...?

Should one just ignore things like this and move on? Flag one of the edits (but there's nothing wrong with them...)? Post a comment on one of the edited questions, saying "Well done, thanks for all those edits!" (and maybe point out that he doesn't really need to paste those meta-links on *every* edit comment)? If there wasn't this feeling of something being a bit strange, I'd actually consider finding one of this user's questions or answers and upvoting them, only... *there aren't any*.

Comment: Take each edit in isolation. If it's a good edit, approve it.

Comment: If you're worried about how much reputation they're earning solely from edits, the amount of reputation you can earn from edits is capped at 2000 (the point at which they have sufficient reputation to make edits without community approval).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not really worried, just thought it was strange. Thanks :-)

Comment: Perhaps it's just an experiment to see how much rep and/or badges you can get without actually partaking. In that case, it's probably someone's sockpuppet.

Comment: *"but I still think it's strange behaviour"* But why is what I wonder, being late to the party? Lets forget about the exemplary fellow doing all the nice edits, what is in your head here? You find it strange someone hasn't done and questioning or answering? You don't need to do that to be able to recognize right from wrong, I've never asked a question either - because I don't need to. I rarely answer anything because the tags I frequent have matured and get mostly homework dumps and dupes.

Comment: I suspect it's someone who's not particularly expert (or not confident enough) to answer, but uses SO without ever having a *new* question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey curious - What if awarding bounties keeps the total reputation below 2000?  Is it actually capped at 2000 earned, or does it turn off when reputation is 2000?

Comment: @Robert, [According to the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), that's not quite correct: "You gain reputation when [...] suggested edit is accepted: +2 (_up to +1000 total per user_)", or is the help center wrong here ?

Comment: @MrLister: Ah good, at least I'm not the only one wondering what's going on. Hard for me to switch off that part of my brain... but I'm starting to be convinced by the answers and other comments that it's probably nothing.

Comment: @Gimby: I suppose having come across that other user I mentioned recently put me in a somewhat suspicious frame of mind - I was seeing the opposite of quick, single-tag edits and couldn't help but be curious why such a low-ranking user would make so many good-quality edits. As I said, I actually looked up their profile with the intent of upvoting one of their posts, thinking they must be high-quality as well. It was only when I saw that there weren't _any_ posts that curiosity turned to... well, not suspicion, but something close to it, I suppose. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Gimby Still, you have over twice as many posts as you have revisions. SO is first and foremost a _question and answer_ site, not an _edit other people's posts_ site!

Comment: @MrLister Nobody can deny what you say, but questions and answers do need editing. Lots and lots of editing. As to "other people's posts" - as soon as you post it you contributed it to the community. The reason why we can edit stuff not our own is because the concept of ownership is as loose as it should be.

Comment: @Gimby You mininterpret my comment. I'm not trying to go in to discussions about whether editing is good. Personally I've also edited lots of posts (thousands in fact). My point was simply that I agree with the OP it's very strange for someone to have no posts at all; only edits; no matter how good the edits.

Comment: @MrLister that's fine, then we disagree on that too :) Nothing wrong with differing opinions.

Comment: @jonasz The Help Center takes precedence.  The cap at 2000 occurs because you're given full editing privileges at that time; you no longer earn rep from edits when that happens.

Comment: How to handle users who does good edits? Well, appreciate them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just look at the edit.

If the edit is good, approve.
If it is bad, reject.
If you aren't sure, simply skip.

If someone only wants to contribute by copy-editing posts, that's their decision, and provided they do it well, very welcome.
There are lots of posts which would benefit from some editing-love, we won't run out anytime soon...

Comment: As I said, I haven't come across a "bad" edit by this user yet, so I'm happy to approve them. I just can't shake the suspicion that something is off, e.g. getting lots of +2s for editing, then awarding bounties to stay under the threshold for when you get rep for editing...? Though I agree, I can't see how any of this could be harmful, hence I thought I'd ask here in case anyone else can. If not, happy to ignore and move on.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter: Don't worry. [One cannot get more than 1K](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) rep total for suggesting edits, ever, doesn't matter how it's used. And if he gets rep that way, he's welcome to it.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter If a user consistently makes good and valueable edits below 2k then that it a positive action in the community and very much appreciated. That appreciation takes form in giving +2 for every approved edit they got until they reach 2k. Why would you feel something is "off" about that anymore then it would be on a user getting consistent upvotes on consistently good posts?

Answer (score 11):

Some users want to do stuff, but aren't (yet) comfortable directly participating in Q&A. Editing lets them help us, gives them the satisfaction of giving something back, and lets them get enough rep to unlock all of the desirable creature comforts.

I think you'll also see quite a few people getting their 'feet wet' by also contributing to documentation once it ships. It's another way for folks that get a lot out of the site to give something back while earning a modicum of reputation along the way.

Q&A, well, the way we do it, can be daunting to outsiders. If you think about it for a minute:

- The highest scored stuff tends to be *extremely* well written. Folks don't always feel comfortable enough with their writing ability to jump in immediately.
- We have a concept of negative reputation. This is a pretty big deterrent *if* you're not confident.

So, editing (and soon, documentation) is a great way for people to beef up their writing chops, get some rep and just feel included.

Comment: Fair enough - maybe my brain is just seeing strange patterns where there are none, or at least none with any evil plans of world domination... ;-) And good point about the documentation, looking forward to seeing what that'll be like.

Comment: You mention documentation, im intrigued. Will people get reputation for cleaning and editing documentation of their favorite language? If so, where will this rep be? On SO?

Comment: @Magisch They're probably referring to the [Documentation](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com) site, which is currently in beta.

Comment: @Magisch In case you're not in Docs beta, I reposted the tentative [Documentation reputation rules](https://gist.github.com/normalhuman/c417375496f06dd4fe59).